# How to strip thumb from widget

Tags: customization, thumbnails, post-thumbnails

I v made a customization on my theme, and some widget display where only title is shown without thumb.But the thing is i dont know how to remove this thumb so i v made a custom thumb size and in function added size 0,0 but i want to remove it . So the thumb get generated and in category page it could be shown but inside this widget i dont want it there as this has slowed my site. This is a part of that widget with thumb inside

```
<div class="widget-container">
            <div class="widget-inner-list">
                <h4 class="widget-header"><?php echo $title; ?></h4>
                <ul class="catonlylist-links2">
                    <?php $recent = new WP_Query(array( 'cat' => $categories, 'showposts' => $posts_num )); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
                    <li>
                        <?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) { ?>
                        <div class="widget-img">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('lists'); ?></a>
                        </div><!--widget-img-->
                        <?php } ?>
                        <div class="catonlylist-links2-text">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                        </div><!--home-links2-text-->
                    </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
            </div><!--widget-inner-list-->
        </div><!--widget-container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should remove this part:**

```
<?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) { ?>
<div class="widget-img">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('lists'); ?></a>
</div><!--widget-img-->
<?php } ?>
```

.
**Just to explain... This conditional statement askes... if there is a thumbnail run the code in between me and my closing tag...**

```
<?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) { ?>

<?php } ?>
```

**This part "echoes" the thumbnail container (div) & its href wrapper & the thumbnail itself.**

```
<div class="widget-img">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('lists'); ?></a>
</div><!--widget-img-->
```

Comment: Hey @kaiser (responding to your edit)... since he's a new user i thought i should help but to point that its not a wp question... i remember at the beginning i had some problem understanding the structure and where to post what ;)

Comment: Completely understand that. If I would be an mod, I would've moved it to a comment.